# Is it possible to 'embed' cache manifest directly in HTML?

Tags: html, base64, cache-manifest

I've only recently been reading about cache manifest and how it's type must be served as `text/cache-manifest`.  Seeing this, I thought this being possible might might be a reasonable assumption:

```
<html manifest="data:text/cache-manifest;base64,...">
```

In the same way you can use it for `text/html`, `application/pdf`, `image/...`, etc.  From initial experimentation, it seems to fail, plus [this validator](http://manifest-validator.com/) doesn't like it.

Could this work?  Have I gone wrong elsewhere?  Could it be embedded any other way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems like some others beat me to the point, [here](http://remysharp.com/2011/01/31/simple-offline-application/):

> Note: the manifest file is subject to the same-origin rule, in that
>   you can’t point the manifest attribute to something like
>   http://simpleapp.com/self.manifest. Equally, **you can’t base64 encode
>   the manifest file** as some people have asked in the comments – that
>   would be really awesome!